# How to handle multiple deployment environments with different db names in an avro java project?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro

I have a kafka app that listens to mysql binlog using debezium connector. So I put some .avsc schema files and avro maven plugin creates java class files. My problem is my application is deployed on a staging kubernetes environment and after passing tests it is automatically deployed to a pre and then production environment.

The name of the database table I am listening to production environment is mysql.company.orders but in staging environment the name is mysql.staging_company.orders This change in db name causes drastic changes in avro schema file, generated class files and naturally the usage of such files in my application code. Is there any standard way to handle this or I should overload my methods for all the types (having three overloads for each method) and then dynamically use them based on the environment?

Comment: Not sure if it will help or not, but usually this is the sort of thing that is handled by the deployment tool (such as Bamboo, Jenkins, Octopus Deploy, etc). Basically, depending on the build you are using, transformations are applied. ***That being said, however***, the more standard approach would be to have the same table names, and change, at most, the connection string and database name to identify between the various databases you have.

Comment: @npinti Good point. This is a wrong design decision that's made long ago and entangled so much in the system that cannot be changed now.
Second point is Jenkins cannot help in this matter. This name defines the name of my type so I cannot dynamically decide in my code.

Comment: So, just to see I understand, you will need to have a different class (mapping to the table you have) according to the environment you are in?

Comment: @npinti yes. That's how debezium binlog connector works. It creates java class files based on avro schema files. These schema files are dependent on the name of database.

Comment: The only way I see this working is through the use of some factory class, which you can wrap around your debezium implementation to give you an object instance (defined by an interface) according to which environment you are working on.

Comment: @npinti yes seems like the only way. But that ruins the whole purpose of the test and autonomous deployment. Plus I have to keep repeated code in sync.

Comment: You can try to use Avro aliases to redefine your namespace during consumption. But really sounds like you have to disable the Avro schema generator in Debezium

Comment: @cricket_007 By avro schema generator you mean creating java classes automatically based on avro schema files or you mean I write even reader schema files myself?

Comment: I mean setting `value.converter.auto.register.schemas=false`